# convert javascript to jquery using asp:button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<script>
   function addOption() {
        document.getElementById('userType').value = "Error";
    }function addOption1() {
        document.getElementById('userType').value = "How";
    }function addOption2() {
        document.getElementById('userType').value = "Lifetouch";
    }function addOption3() {
        document.getElementById('userType').value = "Mobile";
    }function addOption4() {
        document.getElementById('userType').value = "Order";
    } function addOption5() {
        document.getElementById('userType').value = "Promotions";
    } function addOption6() {
        document.getElementById('userType').value = "Quality";
    }
   
</script>

<select id="userType" disabled>
  <option value="Select" selected id="myDefault">Select</option>
  <option value="Error">Error</option>
  <option value="How">How to</option>
  <option value="Lifetouch">Lifetouch</option>
  <option value="Mobile">Mobile app</option>
  <option value="Order">Order status</option>
  <option value="Promotions">Promotions</option>
  <option value="Quality">Quality</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="Error" onclick="addOption()">Error</button>
<button type="button" name="How to" onclick="addOption1()">How to</button>
<button type="button" name="Lifetouch" onclick="addOption2()">Lifetouch</button>
<button type="button" name="Mobile app" onclick="addOption3()">Mobile app</button>
<button type="button" name="Order status" onclick="addOption4()">Order status</button>
<button type="button" name="Promotions" onclick="addOption5()">Promotions</button>
<button type="button" name="Quality" onclick="addOption6()">Quality</button>
```

i want to change the asp:button event and  jQuery any ideas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button.option").click(function() {
    $("#userType").val($(this).attr("name").indexOf(" ") > -1 ? $(this).attr("name").substr(0, $(this).attr("name").indexOf(" ")) : $(this).attr("name"));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="userType" disabled>
  <option value="Select" selected id="myDefault">Select</option>
  <option value="Error">Error</option>
  <option value="How">How to</option>
  <option value="Lifetouch">Lifetouch</option>
  <option value="Mobile">Mobile app</option>
  <option value="Order">Order status</option>
  <option value="Promotions">Promotions</option>
  <option value="Quality">Quality</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="Error" class="option">Error</button>
<button type="button" name="How to" class="option">How to</button>
<button type="button" name="Lifetouch" class="option">Lifetouch</button>
<button type="button" name="Mobile app" class="option">Mobile app</button>
<button type="button" name="Order status" class="option">Order status</button>
<button type="button" name="Promotions" class="option">Promotions</button>
<button type="button" name="Quality" class="option">Quality</button>
```

In the future, please provide a proper example and clear definition of what you are trying to accomplish. You will also want to include any examples of code you have tried. Please also take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: may be its working  i need a asp .net <asp:button ></asp:button> format if u know that please explain

Comment: @peermohameds ASP is a Server Side scripting language whereas JavaScript is a Client Side scripting language. What you writ in ASP.NET creates or outputs HTML to be used by the browser. If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example